Speed up Docker build in CodeBuild
I have a Dockerfile that is pretty slow to build (15 mins). The big problem areas are:

Adding system dependencies to the base Node image in order to perform step 2...
yarn install (for which the extra system dependencies are needed)

The system deps and yarn package deps do not change very often. Locally, the Docker layer cache does wonders here. I believe I can turn on Docker layer caching in CodeBuild, but I don't think I have frequent enough builds to be working with a hot cache.
I had a couple of thoughts, but each came with reservations:

Prebuilding this part as a custom base image, but it got tricky when trying to reason about the case where these dependencies do change. I'm also a little worried about managing this in my local env (e.g. if the base image lives in a private ECR repo)
Using S3 as a cache, but my final image is ~1GB (and the layers are larger before the exporting final), so I feel like this could be slow (and expensive?)

Any suggestions here, either on my existing ideas or something new, would be greatly appreciated!
